# Display the last name and hire date of every employee who was hired in 1994

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem of my code. I want to Display the `LAST_NAME` and `HIRE_DATE` of every employee who was hired in 1994

I tried to execute using these code but it doesn't work the result is empty between the `LAST_NAME` and `HIRE_DATE`.

Here is my table and code:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
   (    
    EMPLOYEE_ID INT, 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25), 
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25), 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20), 
    HIRE_DATE DATETIME, 
    JOB_ID VARCHAR(10), 
    SALARY DECIMAL(8,2), 
    COMMISSION_PCT DECIMAL(2,2), 
    MANAGER_ID INT, 
    DEPARTMENT_ID INT
   );


SELECT LAST_NAME, datepart(year,HIRE_DATE) FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE datediff (YEAR,HIRE_DATE,GETDATE) = 1994
```

Here is an image of my table:
[image]

Comment: Your datediff function is,  in effect,  asking who was hired one thousand nine hundred ninety four years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date FROM employees
WHERE year(hire_date) = 1994
```

the use of function, however, will inhibit the query optimizer to use any index available on `hire_date` column.

So, this should work better:

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date FROM employees
WHERE hire_date >= '1994-01-01' and hire_date < '1995-01-01'
```

Comment: You should never use functions on fields like that, it makes in non-SARGable. The correct way is `hire_date >= '19940101' and hire_date < '19950101'`

Comment: @GurV thank you. so much .  the uses in putting >=  to start execute from all 1994 and put < to make sure it will not execute 1995 only all 1994

Comment: @JamesZ thank you also its really work.   it is the same also in putting like     SELECT last_name, hire_date FROM employees
WHERE hire_date >= '1994-01-01' and hire_date < '1995-01-01'